# xsl numbering with same elements next to

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to format some xml data with the following structure

```
<list>
  <item>
    Test
  </item>
  <item>
    Testt
  </item>
  <or-item>
    TestOr
  </or-item>
  <or-item>
    TestOrr
  </or-item>
  <item>
    Testtt
  </item>
  <or-item>
    TestOrrr
  </or-item>
  <item>
    Testttt
  </item>
</list>
```

with `xsl:number` the `or-item` must be formatted with the second level count on that position. I know it would be better to structure the `or-item` inside that `item` but the data is given like that.

I need a way to count the `or-item` next to the current `or-item` to calculate the numbering for `xsl:number`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.1"
xmlns:axf="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="list">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <div>
      <xsl:number count="item"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="or-item">
    <div style="padding-left: 10px">
      <xsl:number value="count(//or-item)" format="a) "/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Edit

I am using XSLT 1.1 with xsltproc on linux but 2.0 whould be possible if neccessary

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the result you want to produce for the XML sample you have shown? Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version I1.1 never really existed as spec) do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the target format is HTML, it seems you could rely on creating the appropriate nested HTML ordered lists by using `xsl:for-each-group` and `group-starting-with="item"`:

```
  <xsl:template match="list">
      <ol>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="item">
              <li>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  <xsl:where-populated>
                      <ol>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
                      </ol>
                  </xsl:where-populated>
              </li>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </ol>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="or-item">
      <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivJrM

That example uses some XSLT/XPath 3 stuff like `were-populated` and `tail` but in case that XSLT 2 compatility is needed then it could be replaced by `<xsl:if test="subsequence(current-group(), 2)"><ol><xsl:apply-templates select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)"/></xsl:if>`.

And of course the use of HTML ordered lists is not necessary, if needed/wanted you could just transform the input to nested divs with the used grouping approach and then in a second step use `format-number` as you seem to want to do:

```
  <xsl:template match="list">
      <xsl:variable name="nested-list">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="item">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="tail(current-group())"/>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>              
      </xsl:variable>
      <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$nested-list"/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <div>
      <xsl:number/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="or-item">
    <div style="padding-left: 10px">
      <xsl:number format="a) "/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivJrM/1

Comment: hmm `saxon` knows the `tail` function but there are problems in `Altova`  ... is there any replacement?

Comment: @Pascal, yes, `tail(current-group())` is essentially `current-group()[position() gt 1]` or `subsequence(current-group(), 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the expected output by simply adjusting the `xsl:number instruction`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/list">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <div>
        <xsl:number/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="or-item">
    <div style="padding-left: 10px">
        <xsl:number level="any" from="item" format="a) "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```